# Overriding layouts in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have android library project--SampleLibrary which contains

1. a layout file sample_layout.xml in layout folder
2. and corresponding java file which uses this layout file sampleLayout.java

I also have SampleExample android project in same workspace which uses

1. SampleLibrary as source
2. It also contains sample_layout.xml in its layout folder which is same as that of sample_layout.xml in SampleLibrary except it contains one more button.

Now if I want to set event listeners for this button in SampleExample project. How can this be done without making changes in sampleLayout.java? We are allowed to make changes in SampleExample project.

Comment: show ur code so we can help you,

Answer (score 0):

So change the `sample_layout.xml` name inside the SampleExample project, this will be the safest thing to do.

Comment: this sample_layout.xml is used in sampleLayout.java in SampleLibrary and so we cannot change the name

Answer (score 0):

You have to override SampleLayout.java in SampleExample.

Comment: I cannot override it as SampleExample uses SampleLibrary as source. As it already contains SampleLayout.java, overriding SampleLayout.java will make 2 instances of SampleLayout.java in SampleExample and project won't get built

Comment: I meant creating new class with added functionalities. ex. `NewSampleLayout extends SampleLayout`

Comment: Then there is no way to change behaviours in library without changing the library.

Comment: Can android fragments be used?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to override SampleLayout.java. 
Try something like this:

```
public class SampleLayout extends your.lib.SampleLayout {

private Button newButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    newButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.thebutton);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this); 
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (newButton.getId() == view.getId()) {
        // button pressed
    } else {
        super.onClick(view); 
       // library handles this
    }
}
```